# Where is the position of each paramter in a smart contract function when encoded as inputdata in a transaction

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-invocation, abi, encoding

When I reviewed the BEC attack, I found the position of each parameters value in real transaction was not corresponding in to definition of function in smart contract.

The exploit transaction is at:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xad89ff16fd1ebe3a0a7cf4ed282302c06626c1af33221ebe0d3a470aba4a660f.

In transaction inputdata, the `address[]` value is put at the second, but in function definition, it's in the first. Another question is why the value of `_value` take three values.

So is there any rule for setting 'inputdata' value position in transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are encoded based on the Contract ABI Specification. It is hard to get through, but [these docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html) have all the answers to your question.

---

The transaction in question is passing in two parameters: a dynamic array of addresses (`_receivers`) and a static uint256 (`_value`). When encoding the parameters, the EVM looks to see if the parameters are static or dynamic.

Static parameters are encoded in a fairly straightforward manner--they are converted to their hex representation and then concatenated into the input data hex string.

Dynamic values are more interesting. Use [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types) section of the docs to fully understand, but the idea is that the encoded data is the location of the data. The encoded data itself is then concatenated to the end of the input data hex string, *after* all of the dynamic types. For dynamic types, the length of the parameter is then included, followed by the data itself.

Breaking down the transaction you posted:

> 0x83f12fec000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000b4d30cac5124b46c2df0cf3e3e1be05f421190330000000000000000000000000e823ffe018727585eaf5bc769fa80472f76c3d7

`0x83f12fec`

This is the method ID of the function called (in this case, `batchTransfer(address[] , uint256)`)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040`

This is the *location* of the first (dynamic) parameter. This is the location where `_receivers` lives, but is not the data itself.

`8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

This is the `_value` parameter that was sent with the transaction.

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`

This is the length of the dynamic `_receivers`. In this case, there were 2 receivers.

`000000000000000000000000b4d30cac5124b46c2df0cf3e3e1be05f42119033`

The first receiver.

`0000000000000000000000000e823ffe018727585eaf5bc769fa80472f76c3d7`

The second receiver.

Comment: Thanks very much! It totally addresses my problems!